# How to convert a .vmwarevm file to VirtualBox vm format?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I am using macOS AND want to clone my machine form `.vmwarevm` format to any popular VirtualBox friendly format.

I was using a VM with my college Fusion license and after I graduated, I was not legally allowed to use that license any longer.

Now I'm on a trial version of Fusion and want to know how can I clone/convert my machine to a VirtualBox format.

Comment: What OS is installed on the VM? `.vmwarevm` is just a folder, by the way, much like `.app` “files”. You can take a look inside opening it from the context menu.

Comment: Ubuntu is in the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answers your question:
[Link](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-virtual-machines-vmware-virtualbox/)

Quotes from source:

> Note: if you are using VMware Workstation, you can also export the VM as an .ovf file by navigating to “File” and then selecting the option “Export to OVF.”

Screenshot from source (import window in Virtualbox):

[image: Import windows]

So basically you just hit export in WMWare and then import it in Virtualbox.
The file format you'll be using is .OVF.